# Why does this simple urlopen() function generate ssl error?

Tags: python, ssl, beautifulsoup

I made a program scrapping simple wikipedia page. I refer the book 'Web Scraping with python'.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for link in bsObj.findAll("a"):
  if 'href' in link.attrs:
    print(link.attrs['href'])
```

But It generate ssl errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1240, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1083, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1128, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1079, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 911, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 854, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1237, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 376, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 983, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 628, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:646)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    html = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon")
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 162, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 471, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 581, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 503, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 686, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 465, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 483, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1283, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1242, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:646)>
```

Python version is 3.5.0.

And book doesn't deal with this kind of error. Do I have to install the package related with ssl using pip?

Comment: Please don't try to scrape Wikipedia pages. Learn to use [the API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) instead. Sure, there's a bit of a learning curve, but you get the data you want in JSON rather than having to parse it with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for advice, but I want to know why this error occurs, too ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure because I don't use `urllib.request` (I use the 3rd party [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module these days for HTTP stuff). But `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon` redirects to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon`, and that requires SSL. negotiation.

Comment: It worked fine in both 3.3 and 3.4, but I don't have 3.5.  Can you try other websites?  Can you try 3.3 or 3.4?

Comment: @dstudeba python 3.5 is crazy. It works at 3.4...

Answer (score 0):

SSL error occurs when the domain listed on the SSL certificate presented by the server does not match the domain that the browser is connected to. For a HTTPS session to commence, the domain on the certificate must exactly match the domain in the browser address bar.

1. This means that the url you are trying to open using

   ```
   urllib.request.urlopen(url)
   ```

   is not giving back the correct http response.
   Now, You can try one of these things -
2. Check your http/https proxy handler using

   ```
   urlib.request.proxyHandler()
   ```
3. Try to go through, https server if you believe the url is secure and you don't want to make sure it contains a SSL authentication.